# How to upload Spring Boot application using RabbitMQ messaging to AWS EC2?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I have a functioning application using Spring Boot, Rabbit MQ & MySQL DB locally. I'm curious, how I can upload this app to the AWS Environment and get it working seamlessly.

The only part where I'm lost is how to get RabbitMQ in the cloud? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three options for your needs :

- **Use AmazonMQ managed service**. This uses ActiveMQ under the hood, and supports the AMQP protocol (so you can continue to use the RabbitMQ client). Here's an article on how to do it : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-from-rabbitmq-to-amazon-mq/.
- **Use a third-party managed service** (such as CloudAMQP). This is similar to the first option, but you can choose a RabbitMQ provider if you wish.
- **Install RabbitMQ on an EC2 instance and manage it yourself**. This is the most flexible option, but it will require more effort on your part and it will probably cost more. I would recommend this option only if you have special requirements that are not met by using a hosted service.

In all cases, I would also recommend to **use a messaging library** such as Spring Messaging or Apache Camel to isolate your code from your messaging implementation. This will reduce the boilerplate code you need for messaging and allows you to focus on your application logic.